# How do I write this tricky SQL / JPA query?

Tags: sql, jpa

(I'm using Oracle and JPA (from Java EE 5, WebSphere 7)).

I have a Project class, Project has a list of Tasks.

Each Task has a sequence number so I can determine the task's sequential order (Task.seq), and a assigned user (Task.userId), and a String status Task.status ("IN_PROGRESS" or "COMPELTE").  The tasks for a project get "COMPLETED" by their assigned user in their numerical sequence.

My problem is ... this is the tricky bit ... I need a query that does the following:

Given a userid, find all Projects where the current task of that project is assigned to the user.  (The 'current task' is the first task found in numerical sequence that has a status of "IN_PROGRESS".)

I'm not great with SQL, and pretty new to JPA -- please help!

PS. For example, here's the query I'm currently using that gets me all Project objects with the task list populated:

```
select distinct p from Project p left join fetch p.taskList
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To think about this, start by finding the first task for the user.  Then, join in the project information, and select whatever you want to know about the projects:

```
select distinct p.*
from (select userid, projectid, min(t.seq) as firstseq
      from Task t
      where t.userid = <userid> and 
            t.status = 'IN PROGRESS'
      group by userid, projectid
     ) u join
     Task t
     on t.projectid = u.projectid and
        t.seq = u.firstseq join
     Project p
     on p.projectid = u.projectid
```

I'm assuming the task has a projectid, although you don't explicitly say that.

This solution should work in just about any database.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
Select p from Project p join p.tasks t where t.user = :user and t.seq = (Select min(t2.seq) from Task t2 where t2 = t and t2.status = 'IN_PROGRESS')
```